# Proxy .cfm to a CF server

Tags: nginx, coldfusion, proxy, coldfusion-9

I'd like to use Nginx as a proxy server for ColdFusion.

I'm forced to use ColdFusion 9. CF Developer Edition is installed using multiserver. The inbuit jrun server is running on port 8300 and I can access the admin panel at `http://localhost:8300/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm` as described in the installer.

I have a hosts entry:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

and the nginx config file is the following:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        root /home/user/dev/cf;

        index index.cfm;

        location ~ \.cfm$ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8300;
        }
}
```

There is a file `/home/user/dev/cf/index.cfm` with the following content:

```
<cfoutput>
    <h1>Dupa</h1>
</cfoutput>
```

However, when I access `http://example.com` or `http://example.com/index.cfm`, I get a 404 error. The docroot also contains static files which are served normally, e.g. `http://example.com/sitemap.xml`.

Am I missing something? What should I do to proxy cfm files to the cf server?

Comment: It might be a typo in your question but you mention two different paths there: `root /home/user/dev/cf;` and `There is a file /home/user/cf/index.cfm`. Is the difference in paths your problem?

Comment: No, this is not the actual path (edited for brevity for the sake of readability of the question).

Comment: Did you get this figured out?